# Is game of life an example to halting problem?

Tags: halting-problem, cellular-automata

I am working on a solution that can say if an initial composition is going to live forever or eventually die without calculating each generation until it reaches a stable or an ever-repeating cycle in a finite-grid. (I know Game of Life is supposed to work in an infinite grid but we all gotta start somewhere)

I am seeing some patterns in my solution (it would take so long to explain it, but basically I am representing the inital compositions in binary) but... that's pretty much it. I haven't found the exact formula or function yet.

Is it impossible in literal terms to find it? Or just pretty hard? Or does this question even make sense? (Maybe no one knows whether it exists or not and there is no way to prove or disprove it's existence?)

Comment: Maybe this [article](https://www.wolframscience.com/nks/notes-12-8--halting-problems/) would help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Undecidability

Comment: It's possible to simulate a Turing machine in the Game of Life, so the halting problem applies.